# Waf PDB output in Windows (MSVC toolset)?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, debug-symbols, pdb-files, waf

I used to use GDB + Clang, and I'm realizing how much I took stack traces for granted.

How does one have Waf generate PDB output in the directory of a built executable?

My configuration passes /Zi and /debug flags to the compiler/linker, but the only pdb file I'm seeing (for any of my several binary outputs located in subdirectories of my build directory) is a vc110.pdb file in the root of the build directory (and no, there's no executable binary of any kind in the root of my build directory).

Extra information available on request - even after some Googling and other info-finding tasks I'm just not sure what would be useful for me to put down at the moment (as in, I'd probably need to dive into the Waf code to know what the heck to put down...).

Answer (score 1):

The debugging database is only generated my Visual Studio if you request it. Run the build again with `python waf.py -v -v build` to see what switches Waf sends to VS.

`link.exe` should be given `/DEBUG` and to `cl.exe` `/Zi` and `/FS`. You set them in your wscript using:

```
def configure(ctx):
    ...
    ctx.env.CXXFLAGS += ['/Zi', '/FS']
    ctx.env.LINKFLAGS += ['/DEBUG']
```